# Manually call passport for authentication

Tags: node.js, passport-local

I develop a restful nodeJS API protected by a oauth2 authentication using passport.

```
  var express = require('express');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    var app = express();

    app.use(passport.initialize());

    // Create our Express router
    var router = express.Router();
    var creatureController = require('./controllers/creature');

    router.route('/creature').get(passport.authenticate('accessToken', {session: false}), creatureController.getProfile);
```

In this case, the route is protected and it requires to send a valid token in order to access to the route.

I want to find a way to authenticate my "users" manually, by calling a function, which take the username and password of the user I want to authenticate.

Comment: If you want to authenticate your users manually, then why are you using passport?

Comment: I think he means by manually calling the `authenticate` method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Passport exposes a [`req.login()`](http://passportjs.org/docs/login) function that can be used to login the user manually.

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = User.findOrCreate(req.body);
    // … your authentication or whatever
    req.login(user, function(err){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.redirect('/home');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually use passport.authenticate this way

```js
passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
/**
* user - the user objec
* info - info about the error
*/                
console.log(err, user, info);
              
})(req, res, next);
```